# Handling username changes in Subversion server with Windows Authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, svn, windows-authentication, visualsvn-server

I have a Subversion server (version 1.7.2) that is fronted by Apache 2.2.21 using basic Windows/Active Directory authentication. Really it's just using the Visual SVN Server 2.5 package with Windows authentication enabled (Basic authentication, not Integrated Windows Authentication). The SVN server runs on a dedicated Windows Server 2008 R2 machine if it matters.

One of our users recently went through a name change and their Windows username was updated to reflect the name change, but their SID remains the same. Unfortunately SVN still shows the user's old Windows username every time the user commits.

Is there a way to get SVN to recognize the user's username change for future commits?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had to reboot the Subversion server for unrelated maintenance so I'm not sure if it was the full reboot of Windows or just a restart of the Visual SVN server, but after the reboot, Subversion now recognizes the user's username change

Answer (score 0):

Did *all* of the user's name attributes get updated correctly?

Not sure whether it's using the full name or the straight username - if it's the full name, check `cn`, `displayName`, `name`, `givenName`, and `sn`.  If it's the username, check `sAMAccountName`, `msDS-PrincipalName`, `userPrincipalName`.  I've seen a lot of cases where an application sees old info because the attribute that it's looking at isn't up to date with the change.

Comment: Yes, there's no trace of the user's old last name in any of the attributes (I used Softerra's LDAP Browser to confirm), other than a `proxyAddresses` value where the AD admins left the old email address in the system just in case.